# Java code to update xml file content

Tags: java, xml

I am very new to both java and xml. I am trying to do the following :

I have a text file called “text.txt” containing the following information :

```
Brad Wood, 4562785341, 413, 3
Laury Mitchell, 7822345321, 413, 2
Jack Foster, 6454532347, 8, 13
```

On each line, I have : the name of the customer, the credit card number, the product number and the quantity purchased.

I also have an xml file called “inv.xml” containing the inventory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inventory>
<product number="8" price="382.00" quantity= "24" />
<product number="46" price="24.00" quantity= "85"  />
<product number="413" price="12.00" quantity= "230"  />
</inventory>
```

The java code needs to update the inventory contained in the xml file depending on the purchases from the file “text.txt”. I placed my java code in a file called “InvUpdate.java” and the command “java InvUpdate text.txt inv.xml” needs to modify the file “inv.xml” to subtract the quantity of product purchased. In this example, following the execution of the program the file “inv.xml” will contain the following information :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inventory>
<product number="8" price="382.00" quantity= "11" />
<product number="46" price="24.00" quantity= "85"  />
<product number="413" price="12.00" quantity= "225"  />
</inventory>
```

The file “inv.xml” will always contain only one “product” element for each attribute value “number”. Also there is no invalid coding in the text file “text.txt”. I don’t know how many purchases there can be. It is possible to have a negative amount of product in the inventory.

I think it should be a pretty short program containing less than 50 lines and I don’t need to use try-catch. As I said, I am a beginner and I am trying to learn, so please keep your answers very simple with basic java coding. No advanced coding please.

Here is what I've done so far. I would like to keep my code pretty much as it is right now but just find a way to make it work together by adding what is missing or changing what is wrong. I understand there are many different ways to obtain the same result but I don't want to use coding that I haven't learned yet. As I said I am a beginner and I am trying to understand what I am doing. What you see below is pretty much an example of where I am at. Thank you for your help.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class InvUpdate {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  

    FileReader file = new FileReader("text.txt");  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);  
    String line = null;  

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {    
        String str[] =line.split(",");    
        System.out.println(str[2] +","+str[3]);   
    }  
    file.close();  

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder parser = 
    factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = parser.parse(args[0]);
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList nl = root.getElementsByTagName("product");  


    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); ++i) {  
        Element product = (Element) nl.item(i); 

if (product.getAttribute("number").equals(str[2])){  
}  
product.setAttribute("quantity",Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(product.getAttribute("quantity")) - qty));


    }

TransformerFactory tfact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tfact.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty("encoding", "UTF-8");
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("inv.xml");
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(fw);    
transformer.transform(source, result);

}
}
```

Comment: This is obviously some kind of assignment/homework - are you permitted to use third-party libraries, or can you only use JDK classes?

Comment: Only JDK classes.  I would like to keep my code pretty much as it is right now but just find a way to make it work together by adding what is missing or changing what is wrong. I understand there are many different ways to obtain the same result but I can't use coding that I haven't learned yet. What you see above is pretty much an example of what I am learning right now. Thank you @Catchwa

Comment: I am really a beginner so it has to stay simple with basic coding. Thx !

Comment: You need to state what you think is wrong, what you've tried in order to debug the issue, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by designing the solution.  You need to break down the assignment into logical self-contained steps with specified input and output - these will be implemented as separate methods (as I am sure you've learned...)

Here is a starter for ya:

1. read purchases file into internal memory.
   input: file name
   output: `List` of `Purchase` instances
   Method: `List<Purchase> readPurchases(String purchasesFilename)`
2. read invetory file into internal memory.
   input: file name
   output: `List` of `Product` instances
   Method: `List<Product> readInventory(String inventoryFilename)`

So now we know we need some internal data structures.  The methods take care of the IO operations and parsing the lines of text.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I tried to redo my code as follow but it is still not working and I am still kind of lost . I am not sure how to get my array variable to work and also I am not sure if I do it properly to read and get the information from the text file, calculate and update the xml file ...

Comment: @catchwa I am new on this forum where do I post my updated code ?